# Javascript not including formdata in request

Tags: javascript, forms, flask

I'm writing an API. I can successfully send data to it in postman by including it in body > form data. However, this code does not send anything as form-data!

```
addGuild = function () {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "https://gralyn.app/api/server/add/" + window.guild)
    formdata = new FormData()
    formdata.append('prefix', document.getElementById("install-prefix").value);
    req.setRequestHeader("token", this.localStorage.getItem("token"))
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                alert("Success!")
            } else {
                console.log("ERROR: " + this.status)
                openModal("error")
            }
        }
    }
    req.send(formdata)
}
```

The API does not receive a prefix as formdata! I am accessing the prefix in flask via `request.form['prefix']`

Comment: Are you sure the API is able to decode `multipart/form-data` parameters, as opposed to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters?

Comment: @Barmar yes, because If I add it to form-data in postman, it works.

Comment: Check the Network tab in Developer Tools to see what's being sent.

Comment: BTW, get in the habit of declaring local variables rather than assigning global variables. But I don't think that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, javascript wont allow form data in a GET request.